# Make ScrollViewer scroll bound to the right

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer

I am building a calculator application and I have a label to show the term and the result, but when the term gets too long it woudld dissappear. Because of that I implemented a scrollviewer control.

Now what I want to have is that the auto scroll of the scrollviewer is bound to the right, since my label has the content going right to left. See pictures for better explanation

[What it is right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWLZH.png)

[What I want to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnlY0.png)

This is my WPF Code for the relevant parts:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"     Margin="10, 10, 10, 0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Height="50" >
        <Label x:Name="CalculatorTextBlockSolution"  FontFamily="Cambria Math"    HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" FontSize="24"/>
 </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: I have a solution, which is not as elegant as a permanent alignment with calling Scrollviewer.LineRight() after every input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to the ScrollViewer:

```
FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
```

Update (see comments)

Add also to the Label:

```
FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
```

Comment: I tried that, but then somehow the HorizontalContentAlignment control of the label is ignored and the text goes from left to right

Comment: Of course after that you will have to choose: HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"

Comment: Tried that too and then [this](http://i.imgur.com/6an3nxH.png) happens. Where the scroll and the text is bound right, but the start of the text is on the left.

Comment: you can add to the Labl: FlowDirection="LeftToRight" and leave HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"

Comment: By default it takes the FlowDirection from the ScrollViewer, but if you choose different it will take it

Comment: It works now, but by changing HorizontalContentAlignment to "Right"  and keeping FlowDirection="LeftToRight". Thank for the guidance!

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, I see now that I was mistaken in the previous responses. glad to help!